# How to install Dropbox in 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox)

I have tried installing Dropbox via their website (the .deb file), using wget, and adding their repo, and every method has failed. How can I get it to work like it did in 12.04?

I have a clean install on my system, so it's nothing from 12.04 conflicting with it.

Comment: This seems to work exactly how it always has, maybe they updated their website since then?

Comment: It didn't seem to work the first time I tried installing it in 12.10, deleted it all and tried it again, and it seemed to work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  The Dropbox PPA does not support 12.10.