# Mount writable subfolder of read only ntfs partition

Tags: mount, ntfs, read-only

I have dual boot (win7/ubuntu 12.04) system. I want to mount a specific folder (namely the Dropbox folder) from my windows partition in my home directory.
Unfortunately, I am not able to do that.
As far as I understand, I can not 'directly' mount only a folder from a partition, but have to mount the entire partition first and then `mount --bind` the folder.

If I mount the partition writable, there are no problems. But if I mount the partition with

```
sudo mount -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/win
```

and afterwards try

```
sudo mount --bind -w /mnt/win ~/Dropbox/
```

It says

> mount: warning: /home/ope/Dropbox/ seems to be mounted read-only.

I also tried it using /etc/fstab, following the solution given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/251537/mount-specific-ntfs-directory-on-linux).
The relevant fstab lines look like this:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/win ntfs user,ro,umask=0222,defaults 0 0
/mnt/win/Dropbox /home/ope/Dropbox ntfs-3g rbind,user,rw,defaults 0 0
#/mnt/win/Dropbox /home/ope/Dropbox ntfs-3g rbind,user,rw,umask=0222,defaults 0 0
```

The last two lines both create only a read-only mounted folder.
Is there antything I am missing ?
Thank you very much for any hints.

Comment: Why not use dropbox in ubuntu instead? http://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox

Comment: I should have added that ;) : I do want to use it, but I do not want to have the files duplicated under win and ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the filesystem rw somewhere else, then bind mount only that directory to where you want it to appear.  You can then unmount the original mount.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically with a script?

Comment: @feob, yea?  put the commands in a script?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else all ready solved this thing, just follow the link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1927504

Comment: To be honest, I dont think how that helps - the thread is basically about mounting ntfs partitions, or did I miss something ?