# Dropbox (different) installation error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, proxy, software-installation, dropbox

When trying to install dropbox from terminal (using
[How to install Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox) guide),

and trying to install the repository key I get the following:

```
~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.0A2B16zRzS --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
gpg: requesting key 5044912E from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpgkeys: key 5044912E not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Even when I try to just install dropbox itself:

```
$ cd ~ && wget -O - "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
--2014-01-28 14:12:27--  http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64
Resolving <proxy> (<proxy>)... xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to <proxy> (<proxy>)|xxx.xxx.xxx|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2014-01-28 14:12:27 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

however, this should not be a proxy problem as other machines seem to be able to overcome the proxy problem and the Software Center can install it (but then I cannot get the key).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED.

The issue seemed to be the lack of an SSL connection to retrieve the 
nautilus-dropbox directly from Dropbox.

I downloaded it from a Ubuntu/Linux server and now seems to work well. Once installed, had to add the proxies directly to Dropbox (does not seem to automatically pick up Ubuntu's network proxies).

Comment: You can set this as solution, in order to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just download following file with your browser: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_amd64.deb)
Then continue with the installation.

Comment: If I do that, then I need the proprietary daemon, which I think sends me back to the problem above.

Comment: I guess trying will not take very long...