# Dropbox doesn't open and don't sync

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

I download dropbox using software center and dropbox icon shows up in the dash but it wont start syncing. Also dropbox folder doesn't appear on home.

Comment: did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes I tried that reinstall. I think dropbox has some kind of bigger problems with ubuntu now.

Comment: hmm..don't know if this will solve the issue, but you can try installing from command-line. http://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox

Comment: Thank you Ron!! Now my Dropbox is syncing and wokring as it should be. There is somekind of problem when you install Dropbox thru the Software center, but this manual installation works fine.