# How to back up to Dropbox

Tags: backup, dropbox

How do you perform backups to an external server like DropBox using the built in backups program in System Settings?

Comment: Is this a wiki?

Comment: Not really.  Just a question I've had and assumed that other people have had.  I know that this is a big help for me, knowing how to do this.  I'm also looking for issues in this solution.

Comment: What I'm getting at is there's a setup/choice to answer your own question. Is this what you did?

Comment: Yeah.  Is there an issue there?

Comment: It's just a better format

Comment: The wiki is or this?

Comment: When you ask a question there's a checkbox you can tick that lets you answer your own question.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: Then all is good in the world.

Comment: That's Beautiful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to back up to DropBox is to [Install Dropbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox) and create a directory inside the DropBox folder named `deja-dup`.  Then point your backups settings to `Local Folder` `/home/*username*/dropbox/deja-dup/`.  This will backup locally, and then push your backups to Dropbox automatically when you are connected to the internet.