# Starting dropbox at the start of the computer

Tags: dropbox

I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/127187/743263) answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/126198/743263) post, in particular I have followed the binary section, since I couldn't make the other work (I have a problem of dependencies with nautilus), but it seems that dropbox will start only when I type `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`. How do I make dropbox start at the start of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start Dropbox at the startup you need to open `Startup applications` and click on <kbd>Add</kbd>. It would be having 3 fields Name, Command and Comment. Set name as `Dropbox`, command as `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and comment whatever you want and click on <kbd>Add</kbd>

Hope it helps.:-)

Comment: Where do I find startup applications?